# TomEE embedded and custom JAX-RS application deployment

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs, cxf, apache-tomee

I guys,
I'm using TomEE 1.6.0 (jax-rs) with a custom Application :

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class Whatever extends Application {...}
```

I do it in order to customize the base path for my REST services and to add a custom provider for every endpoints of this Application :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openejb-jar xmlns="http://www.openejb.org/openejb-jar/1.1">
    <pojo-deployment class-name="Whatever"> 
      <properties> 
          cxf.jaxrs.providers = WhateverProvider
      </properties> 
    </pojo-deployment> 
</openejb-jar>
```

I have a sample JAX-RS endpoint defined like this :

```
@Path("/whatever")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public class WhateverEndpoint {...}
```

Everything works fine when deploying in TomEE jax-rs (**tomee-maven-plugin:start**).
I can call my services on **/rest/whatever**

The problem is when I want to unit test this service with TomEE Embedded, **WhateverEndpoint** is not deployed...

The configuration I use for the tests setup (@BeforeClass) is the following :

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty(OpenEjbContainer.OPENEJB_EMBEDDED_REMOTABLE, "true");
context = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(properties).getContext();
```

I can test the DAO and so on but not the Endpoints...
When I add a @javax.ejb.* annotation like this :

```
@Singleton
@Path("/whatever")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public class WhateverEndpoint {...}
```

I have something better in the logs :

```
INFO - Initializing network services
INFO - REST Application: http://127.0.0.1:4204/web                -> org.apache.openejb.server.rest.InternalApplication
INFO -      Service URI: http://127.0.0.1:4204/web/whatever         ->  EJB Whatever
INFO -               GET http://127.0.0.1:4204/web/whatever/a  ->      A a(HttpServletRequest)                                         
INFO -   ** Bound Services **
INFO -   NAME                 IP              PORT  
INFO -   httpejbd             127.0.0.1       4204  
INFO -   admin                127.0.0.1       4200  
INFO -   ejbd                 127.0.0.1       4201  
INFO -   ejbds                127.0.0.1       4203
```

What should I do to make it works properly with my custom JAX-RS Application, Path and Provider, just like the TomEE JAX-RS do and without adding ejb annotations ? Should I define additional properties and which one when creating my EJBContainer ? I've see some in the sample applications :

- https://github.com/apache/tomee/blob/trunk/examples/rest-on-ejb
- https://github.com/apache/tomee/blob/trunk/examples/rest-example

But none of them are working.

Here is my pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0-5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomee-embedded</artifactId>
    <version>${tomee.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>openejb-cxf-rs</artifactId>
    <version>${openejb.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomee-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>${tomee.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Overriding openejb.cxf.jax-rs.providers doesn't seem to work neither

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally solved it by adding the EJBContainer.APP_NAME property to the properties passed when creating the embedded container :

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty(OpenEjbContainer.OPENEJB_EMBEDDED_REMOTABLE, "true");
properties.setProperty(EJBContainer.APP_NAME, "/");
context = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(properties).getContext();
```

Comment: It's better late than never ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced the same issue .I resolved this by adding a class in the TestProxyService annotated with @Singleton and then injecting the resource which I wanted to test.The proxy class would invoke the actual resource class .This
For example

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")

public class SampleRestResource{
....methods 

}
@Singleton
@ApplicationPath("/rest")

public class TestResource{
 @Inject
```